# "Ela está mal" ou "Ela está má"?

Tags: gramática, português-brasileiro, concordância-nominal

Aqui no Brasil é comum falar “Ela está mal” para se referir a uma pessoa doente, porém neste caso o sujeito é feminino, mas *mal* é masculino. Seu emprego está errado? Se sim, o correto seria “Ela está má”?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Mal" não é masculino nem feminino; é um **advérbio** e é o contrário de "bem".

Mau é masculino.
Má é feminino.

"Ela está má" até seria possível, mas para indicar o estado de saúde se usa "mal" e "bem".

Se fosse uma característica intrínseca, aí sim se usaria "má":

Ela é **má**.

Answer (score 4):

[*mal*](http://www.aulete.com.br/mal) não é adjectivo masculino. *mal* pode ser advérbio, antónimo de *bem*, ou pode ser substantivo. Então não há nenhum erro de género aqui; *mal* combina com o verbo, não o sujeito.

Aparece que você está a confundir com [*mau*](http://www.aulete.com.br/mau), que é a forma masculina de *má*, antónimos de *bom* e *boa*. Ao meu entender, *mal* e *mau* são homófonos no Brasil, mas não nos outros países de língua portuguesa.

Mas a diferença entre *mal* e *má* não está somente na classe gramatical. Há [muitos significados](http://www.aulete.com.br/mal) de *mal* que combina com a ideia de estar doente:

> - Não bem, de modo imperfeito ou irregular
> - Sem conforto ou bem-estar físico
> - Em má situação
> - Em péssimo estado de saúde

Mas *mau/má* não: revistando [os significados](http://www.aulete.com.br/mau), parece que todos falam mal duma coisa, por exemplo:

> - Que causa ou faz mal
> - Que é malfeito, sem qualidade
> - Velho, estragado

Então *a doença* pode ser **má**, mas a pessoa doente está **mal**.